# Brownie with chocolate mousse on top

Tags: chocolate, brownies, mousse

I want to make a cake that involves a brownie layer with chocolate mousse on top. I just want to use my own trusted brownie and chocolate mousse recipes. I've looked it up and found a few similar [recipes](https://www.lifeloveandsugar.com/2017/10/16/baileys-chocolate-mousse-brownie-cake/).

Now, I'm worried that the chocolate mousse might have a bit of fluids at the bottom that will ruin the brownie layer. Is there anything I can do to improve this (I was thinking of a small layer of chocolate that will prevent absorption of the fluids by the brownie) and is it generally a good idea to combine the two or am I better off making a regular chocolate cake layer instead of a brownie?

Thank you for your advice

Comment: There's a family recipe that's brownie, fudge sauce, pudding (mixed to pie filling consistency), and whipped topping ... the fudge sauce has always provided a sufficient barrier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brownies are thicker than a standard cake sponge, but either can absorb moisture, if you want to prevent that then a thin layer of chocolate frosting would work fine, or as you suggest a thin layer of chocolate.

It is opinion based whether I think a brownie or a sponge would be better with mousse, what I will say is that the consideration is the difference in consistency between the two. A rich, soft mousse on top of soft, fluffy cake may more people than hitting a thick, harder layer of brownie, but it all depends on the effect you are looking for.

Comment: That anwsers all of my questions perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you make the mousse properly, there should be no moisture leaking out of it into or onto the brownie underneath. The thin melted chocolate layer will help keep the layers seperate.